# Shell script to extract line by line data and provide in variable to use further

Tags: bash, shell, sh

File 1 ->
hostname1

hostname2

hostname3

hostname4

.

.

.

.

I want to write a bash script to extract these hostnames and save them in a variable.

Something like below but this does not work

```
count=3
i=1
j=1
count=`expr $count + 1`
while [  $i -lt $count ]
do
        echo The counter is $i

        $j=`sed -n "$i,$i p;$i q" file1.txt`

    echo $i
    i=`expr $i + 1`
    j=`expr $j + 1`
echo $j << this should return hostname1 then hostname2
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
i=1

while read line ;

do 

Var$i=$line

i= ` expr $i + 1 `

done < inputFile
```

This should create `var1`, `var2` ... and assigns each line to a variable

Else an array can also be used

```
i = 0

while read line ;

do 

arr[$i] = $line

i = `expr $i + 1`

done < inputFile
```

The expr syntax is not picking up the back ticks on my answer, please check when you use it

Comment: I don't think that works quite right... bash is very particular about spaces around the "=" sign

Answer (score 0):

```
i=1
while read line ;
do
i=$line
echo $i
i=i+1
done < file.txt
```

Above code has resolved my issue . Thanks